# Can you combine sums under these conditions?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What, exactly, is wrong with combining these? Both sums range from $n=1$ to $\infty$ and are convergent. 
$$2^{1-k}\sum a_n * b_n$$ + $$\sum a_n$$
Can I not combine them to get $$2^{1-k} \sum {a_n(b_n +1)}$$
is is the $2^{1-k}$ that prevents this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Notice that you must rewrite as follows:

$$2^{1-k}\sum a_nb_n+\sum a_n=\sum\left(2^{1-k}a_nb_n+a_n\right)=\sum\left(a_n(2^{1-k}b_n+1)\right)$$

Comment: Oh duh! That's slightly embarrassing. Thank you so much!

Comment: @RyanGoulden No problem, we all make silly mistakes once in a while.